# Reading files in R inside a bash loop

Tags: r, bash, loops

I want to run a R script for 23 chromosomes. The files I need to read are "chr_1.txt, chr_2.txt,...,chr_23.txt"

So I have a bash file

```
#!/bin/bash
for chr in {1..23}; do \

sbatch torunR.sh "chr_$"
done
```

and another bash file (torunR.sh)

```
R CMD BATCH script.R
```

The problem is that I don't know how to read a different "chr_X.txt" files in R (script.R).
I have tried chr_$ or chr_*', for example:

```
geno = read.table(file="chr_*.txt") but it didn't work.
```

Any ideas?? Thanks!!

Comment: I suggest you avoid `R CMD BATCH` and use `Rscript` instead. That makes it easier to get arguments passed to R scripts with the `?commandArgs` function. You'd still need to re-pass the argument` through your `torunR.sh` script. I think `Rscript script.R ${1}` will do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try to do that way. But do you know how to read the different files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in bash scripting so I don't know the necessity of batching, but I would modify your R script to use a command line argument created within the loop.

Your R script would look like this:

```
## script.R
targetFile <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

# optional status message
cat(sprintf("Processing file %s\n", targetFile))

geno <- read.table(file = targetFile)
```

Then modify your bash script to be something along the lines of

```
#!/bin/bash
for chr in {1..23}; do \

Rscript script.R "chr_$chr.txt"
done
```

Result when running bash script (with optional status message):

```
$ ./bashScript.sh
Processing file chr_1.txt
Processing file chr_2.txt
Processing file chr_3.txt
Processing file chr_4.txt
Processing file chr_5.txt
Processing file chr_6.txt
Processing file chr_7.txt
Processing file chr_8.txt
Processing file chr_9.txt
Processing file chr_10.txt
Processing file chr_11.txt
Processing file chr_12.txt
Processing file chr_13.txt
Processing file chr_14.txt
Processing file chr_15.txt
Processing file chr_16.txt
Processing file chr_17.txt
Processing file chr_18.txt
Processing file chr_19.txt
Processing file chr_20.txt
Processing file chr_21.txt
Processing file chr_22.txt
Processing file chr_23.txt
```